# Maclaurin series for functions which are not infinitely differentiable

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was introduced to Maclaurin series through $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ and $e^x$. I have always thought that Maclaurin series works for these functions because they are infinitely differentiable.

My question is; Does this also work for functions which aren't infinitely differentiable? Like for example $$\dfrac{1}{7} x^4 - 12x^2 + 1$$

My intuition tells me that with maclaurin series you can find a function which **somewhat** resembles these types of functions, but not completely/ well.

Comment: What makes you think that function is not infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Try to find the MacLaurin series for this function. I think you will be surprised.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I meant it becomes 0. I am not too familair with mathematical lingo

Comment: @KrisWilliams How would I be able to do that sir? (apart from tedious pen and paper stuff, sorry for being lazy..)

Comment: $0$ is about as differentiable as you can get.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What would the correct term be then?

Comment: This is a very nice function. You may find its Maclaurin series a little boring. But it will tell you a fair bit about Maclaurin series. Compute.

Comment: My god math blows my mind.

Comment: You will need to do the "tedious pen and paper stuff." Mathematics is an adventure. Sometimes the trip is the boring part: think of great explorers sailing for months across the ocean then having a great surprise when they arrive at the destination. Other times, the trip itself is interesting. This is the former.

Comment: A function whose $n$'th derivative is $0$ everywhere is a polynomial of degree $< n$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to answer my own question. But I was so wrong. I found out you can do it using wolfram alpha (chronic laziness, sorry for that):

[image]

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin+expansion+of+17x^4%E2%88%9212x^2%2B1](http://goo.gl/8tyae)

Spot on...

Comment: Btw, this answer is just to show I know the answer now. If anyone has a really good answer to this, be my guest.

Answer (score 1):

Maclaurin's formula is simply a tool to help you find a power series representation of a function centered at zero, ie:
$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n + \cdots,$$
where $a_n = f^{(n)}(0)/n!$.  Your function is already a power series, though, it's just that only three terms are non-zero:

$$1-12x^2 +\frac{1}{7}x^4 = 1 + 0x - 12 x^2 + 0x^3 + \frac{1}{7}{x^4} + 0x^5 + 0x^6 +\cdots$$

All the remaining terms are zero, so there's not much to do.  As you even observed yourself, though, $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for large enough $n$, so Maclaurin's formula yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor/Maclaurin series of a polynomial is simply the same polynomial :)